# What do you call the people who live in condominiums?

Tags: translation

Here in Brazil the people whe live in condominiums are called "condômino", the people who represent all residents are called "síndico" (syndic). I want to translate "condômino". Thanks.

Comment: ***Co-owner*** - the co-owners of a condominium. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/co-owner

Comment: @Josh: I'm not sure the question is about co-ownership.

Comment: @Flater - OP is looking for the English for "condomino".

Comment: Ya, not co-owner. The people live in a condominium, not builded them. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh: I'm aware. But OP is asking about anyone who lives in a condominium, regardless of whether they are the sole owner, share ownership with others, or even rent the place as opposed to own it.

Comment: I doubt there are any terms in common use for all people who live in a structure whose ownership model follows a certain corporate structure, which is what a condominium is; other ownership arrangements in multi-family residential buildings include *housing cooperatives* (*co-ops*),  *townhouses*, and *timeshares*; *strata* is used in some countries. Being a resident or nonresident is entirely orthagonal to being an owner or member or tenant. Can you provide an example sentence that shows how you intend to use this term?

Comment: Of course. Here in Brazil is commom the people live in condominiums like that: http://revistaimoveis.zap.com.br/imoveis/2011/07/condominio4ok.jpg 
I'm building a software like an social network for that. I'm searching for a term to define the people resident and nonresident. 
Sorry if not clear, i'm learning english and the google translate help me.

Comment: If people who live in communes are communists, then obviously people who live in condominiums are condominiumists!

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments (the citation in support of this answer), *there is no specific word in American English for people who live in / own a condominium*, which is apparently “a building or complex of buildings containing a number of individually owned apartments or houses”. (The word isn’t really used in British English.)

To suggest how to translate it one would need context. For example, if it were a newspaper report you would use a phrase like:

> The *condominium residents (or alternatively owners?)* held a meeting to decide how to…

Whereas if it were a technical document you might write something like:

> The mean annual income of *people living in*/*people owning* condominiums has been shown to be 1.8 times higher than *those renting apartments*…

The point that needs to be clarified is whether the term “owner” is valid. I am not familiar with the financial structure of the ownership of this sort of building.

Answer (score 2):

In Canada, where condominiums are common, we would likely say "condo dweller" and would also write this as well, if the writing were informal.

A Google search for "condo dweller" gives results from throughout North America, as well as the alternative "condo-dweller".

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dweller):

> **[place] dweller**
>
> a person or an animal that lives in the particular [place] that is mentioned

"Condominium dweller" would be correct, but "apartment dweller" is much more common, it's even the go-to example on the page.

Comment: Dweller  is a generic term. Resident might fit as well.

Comment: Currently i'm using resident. I'ts sounds good.

Comment: @Josh: Resident fits, if it's already clear that we are talking about condominiums. If that has not yet been established, resident is too broad.